# Looking for a tabbed terminal emulator for windows. Any suggestions?

Tags: windows, terminal, xterm

I've used Hummingbird Exceed as my Xserver on my windows box for years.  I've almost always worked out of xterms, but at times the number of open windows can get a bit out of control and hard to manage.  Wondering if there is a terminal emulator that runs on WinXP that supports tabbed windows, similar to Konsole on KDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at [Poderosa](http://poderosa.sourceforge.net/) ? From the web page

> Tabbed style GUI
>       It is convenient to open multiple connections at the same time.
>   Moreover, you can split the window
>   into panes and allocate each
>   connection. Many different ways to
>   connect| In addition to Telnet and
>   SSH1/2, local cygwin shell and serial
>   ports are supported.

Comment: Gave it a quick try, and so far this looks like exactly what I was looking for.  Looks fairly light weight as well.

Comment: poderosa is a good tool except it is not much maintained and has a couple of serious bugs. Eg. wrapping of longer lines over themselves.That one is killing me. Also when a session is terminated the entire screen is blanked out - you can not recover history.

Answer (score 1):

PuTTyCM (PuTTy Connection Manager)

Too bad, its website is down right now, but the hard link still works http://puttycm.free.fr/download/puttycm.exe

Comment: Thanks! It's been down for a few days and I was looking for a mirror. Good thing the direct link still works.

Answer (score 0):

Does [KDE on Cygwin](http://windows.kde.org/) help?

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at **Super Putty**.

It is similar to PuttyCM with a tabbed layout, but I have found it easier to use for saving and restoring sessions and layouts. Details can be found [here](https://github.com/jimradford/superputty)

***Edit:***

My tool of choice for tabbed SSH on Windows now is [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/).
I have used both *PuttyCM* and *SuperPutty* before. MobaXterm gives you a lot more options including saving credentials, XWindows support out of the box, ability to reconnect sessions, a sftp browser to copy files and many other useful features.